# Should I use useCallback when I navigate to a screen?

Tags: react-native

I want to ask you, should I use "useCallback" when I navigate to any screen or is that unnecessary?

```
...

const navigateToScreen = useCallback(() => {
  navigation.navigate('screen')
}, []);
```

And if I should use "useCallback" then what I have to do in the array ?

Comment: If my answer helped you please consider accepting it and upvoting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you should simply navigate to the other page onClick etc... without UseCallback.

UseCallback is useful when you recreate a function/object on every render, which can be very expensive (if it is a complex calculation, or very large object), and slow your app down a lot. You can pass a variable into the empty array, telling UseCallback to run every time this variable changes.